# Перенос карусели jcarousel в bootstrap

Tags: jcarousel, bootstrap, css

Добрый вечер.

Добавил на сайт карусель jcarousel, хотел, чтобы она заполняла место справа от логотипа, а она почему-то переносится вниз.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить. Пробовал `float:left`, `white-space: nowrap` и прочее, голова уже кругом идет.

[Сайт](http://xn----8sbpah8ayadk9czc.xn--p1ai/)

Answer (score 1):

Измените вёрстку:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="header-logo"><!--<a href="/"><img src="/templates/zarechie/images/banner.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Баннер 480х80"></a>--><a href="/"><img src="/templates/zarechie/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Заречье"></a></div></div><div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8"><!-- JCarousel --></div>
```

Comment: Пояснение - оберните карусель и лого  в отдельные дивы и задайте размеры

Comment: @cema93 сделал, обернул - пропала адаптивность